# Problem loading pre-trained FinBERT model

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to load a pre-trained FinBERT model in python but am getting an error simply trying to load it. I am following the GitHub docs: https://github.com/ProsusAI/finBERT

Following the tutorial, I have created a directory called `bert`, downloaded the model `pytorch_model.bin` and `config.json` file and dropped them in the folder.

I try and call the model using the following code:

```
import os
os.chdir(r'bert')

from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification
import torch

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(r'bert\pytorch_model.bin',
                                                      config = r'bert\config.json')
```

The error trying to load is as follows:

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BertForSequenceClassification:
    size mismatch for classifier.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([3, 768]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([2, 768]).
    size mismatch for classifier.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([2]).
```

My knowledge of this is very basic and if anyone understands what is going on here it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your tensors need to be resized: the shapes are not what the model expects.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks. Do you have a link to any material to show me how I would do this?

Comment: PyTorch has methods that let you do it.   "My knowledge of this is very basic" - I would recommend that you look at fast.ai.  It has 8 video lessons for coders on how to work with fast.ai and PyTorch that are terrific.  You are jumping into the deep end by attempting a BERT model.

Comment: @duffymo I've taken a look into this and one thing I still can't understand is why the tensor size is different. I'm not defining any tensor size so why is there a `current model` with [2, 768] but they are trying to load a model of [3, 768]. Surely if I haven't defined any tensors there shouldn't be a discrepancy.

Comment: @duffymo For example I have managed to load the model using `num_labels=3` but it seems strange that I have to specify this instead of it automatically loading from the checkpoint.

Comment: My guess is that the trained model you're starting with has two variables, but you're adding a third.  I don't know.  I would recommend getting some background before proceeding.

Comment: Just try loading the model: `model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(r'bert')`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is specify the number of labels:

```
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(r'bert\pytorch_model.bin',config = r'bert\config.json', num_labels = 3)
```